# How to restrict root to access a directory used by other user with selinux

Tags: linux, selinux, linux-kernel

I want to restrict the root to access a folder/directory which is created by another user.So that only that user can access that folder not even root. Is there any selinux configuration to do so this as I am not so known to selinux.

Answer (score 3):

Other than creating and applying a policy, it appears the key to it is preventing the use of `setenforce` by the root user:

```
setsebool secure_mode_policyload on
```

I could find a nice how-to you might want to read:
http://blog.siphos.be/2015/07/restricting-even-root-access-to-a-folder